# Looking to extract the filename with regex in a xPath

Tags: javascript, regex

Looking to extract....'`Testing 00000-000-00000-000-56 gram-0020 Something-030 Label'.pdf;` not the extension.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows created="2017-06-19T23:20:33.227+02:00" producer="sqlexec"
   select="SELECT V_Orig_file_name&#xa;FROM Project_Doc_VersionQ&#xa;WHERE V_Id = '00002_0000005592'" startrec="1">
   <row>
      <c n="V_Orig_file_name">Testing 000000-000-00000-000-56 gram-0020 Something-030 Label.pdf</c>
   </row>
</rows>
```

`/rows/row/c/text()` -> gets me....`'Testing 000000-000-00000-000-56 gram-0020 Something-030 Label.pdf`'

How would I include a regex to get... `'Testing 000000-000-00000-000-56 gram-0020 Something-030 Label'`

Comment: Use a positive lookahead such as [`[\w\d -]+(?=\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/SpBhGg/1/)

Answer (score 1):

As YCF_L shows, what you need is a capture group. Whenever you are trying to get a string from another string using regex you'll use a capture group. In most cases, they will be added by using parenthesis in your regex. In your case, you want to select the name and not the extension. There are a ton of ways to do this, but in your case, it seems like you won't know the name of the file necessarily which is why you should use a wildcard selector `.` and you will want this selection to be greedy. I would actually suggest using the `+` greedy quantifier as it will guarantee that you always have a filename. `*` will match 0 or more characters and `+` will match 1 or more. Add the capture group the same as YCF_L's answer and you can either add a period literal `\.` the backslash escapes the period so that it isn't interpreted as a wildcard. You can also add specific extensions if you wish:

```
(.+)\.(pdf|zip|jpg)
```

You'll notice that the second set of parenthesis are there. I bring this up because the first set acts as a capture group (it will put the contents of the match into a variable) and the second set is a non-capturing group because of the `|` characters. In the second set, you are saying it can be `pdf` OR `zip` OR `jpg` and you wont actually have a variable with those matches in there. Hope this helps!

Comment: someone exlain my solution better then me, i think he deserve +1 :)